# How to create a webpage that can be accessed by other IPs (Python wsgiref.simple_server)

Tags: python

How to config that host apart from localhost so that it can be accessed by other computers as well?
Is it doable?

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def hello_world(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 ok'
    headers = [('Content-type','text/plain')]
    start_response(status, headers)

    return ['Hello World']

def run():
    httpd = make_server(localhost, 8000, hello_world)
    print 'Serving on port 80...'
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: code formatting some,  fluff waya

Comment: you can try python -m SimpleHTTPServer in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass an empty string as the hostname, and it will bind to your public network interface:

`httpd = make_server('', 8000, hello_world)`

If you're using Windows, you can confirm this with `netstat` as follows. When I pass `'localhost'` as the first argument, it binds to `127.0.0.1`:

```
PS C:\Users\cody> netstat -a -n | findstr LISTENING | findstr :8000
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

When I pass `''`, it binds to `0.0.0.0`, which essentially means "all interfaces":

```
PS C:\Users\cody> netstat -a -n | findstr LISTENING | findstr :8000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Now even if you're successfully listening on a public interface, if you have a firewall running you may have to disable it before anything external will be able to connect.

Comment: Hi, if I use an empty string, does it mean that I'm using my local host address? Then it still can't be accessed by other computers?

Comment: No, `''` will bind to `0.0.0.0`, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you Cody!! Now I understand better.

Comment: Yes, thank you Cody. Sorry I am new to stack overflow. I didn't know I should mark it accepted. Thanks for reminding.